# Numpy no me funciona

Tags: python, numpy

Intentó hacer un impor numpy as np

Pero me sale esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué hago?

Comment: ¿Has instalado la librería de numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer un `pip install numpy` en la terminal, no se te importa porque no lo tienes instalado ya que no es una librería de las que vienen por defecto